# How do I amend form data before it is saved for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks, actions

I have a custom post type for clinics which has 3 fields; a textarea for the address of a the clinic and two textboxes for latitude and longitude. I want the user to enter the address in the textarea and then when they hit publish I need to hook in, geocode the address and populate the latitude and longitude fields to be stored in the database. If this is successful then when they come to edit the clinic the latitude and longitude fields will be populated. I have the following code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
function geocode_clinic() 
{
if($_POST['post_type']=='clinics') 
{
    $address = urlencode($_POST['fields']['field_52ea48969a9f2']);

    // geocode the address
    $location = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".str_replace(" ", "+", $address)."&sensor=false"));

    if ($data->status=="OK") {          
        $lat = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $lng = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
    } else {
        $lat = $lng = '';
    }

    $_POST['fields']['field_52ea4b66b382f'] = $lat;
    $_POST['fields']['field_52ea4bccb3830'] = $lng;
}
}
add_action('save_post', 'geocode_clinic');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save_post` is much too late to modify the `$_POST` data itself and hope to have it populate to the post save actions (and modifying `$_POST` is usually not necessary anyway). The post has been saved at that point. [Just check the source.](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L2960)

What you should probably be doing is saving your data to the database explicitly using [`update_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta).

Something like this:

```
function geocode_clinic($post_id ) 
{
if($_POST['post_type']=='clinics') 
{
    $address = urlencode($_POST['fields']['field_52ea48969a9f2']);

    // geocode the address
    $location = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".str_replace(" ", "+", $address)."&sensor=false"));

    if ($data->status=="OK") {          
        $lat = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $lng = $data->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
    } else {
        $lat = $lng = '';
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id,'field_52ea4b66b382f',$lat);
    update_post_meta($post_id,'field_52ea4bccb3830',$lng);
}
}
add_action('save_post', 'geocode_clinic');
```

I am not sure those are the key names you want but that is the idea.

Comment: There are WordPress HTTP APIs you can use instead of `file_get_contents`

Comment: @JMau : yes there are. That part of the code comes from the OP and doesn't effect the answer. I didn't alter it, but feel free to make the change if you'd like.

Comment: sorry I don't get it.